# The Dread of Planning a Timeline

Tags: fiction, technique, planning, writers-block, series

I'm working on the second draft of a novel series, and I already have 800 pages written. After re-evaluating the characters and most of their arcs, I've started planning a timeline for each book in the series.

However, **planning a timeline feels so tedious;** I felt the same way on my last project.

In my head, I just want to write, but I know it would be better to plan things out so I don't have to go back to fix scenes. I feel like this will help TONS for the events I've barely planned out and only brainstormed in my head.

I'm wondering if there's a better and less boring way to do this. How I plan is:

- Write a few paragraphs about the event
- Highlight main points
- List all characters in the event
- Graph the time span between each sub-event ("After 2 weeks, he...")

Any tips and feedback you have helps!

(P.S., I have read through a similar post, [How do I stay motivated while planning a series of novels?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/40766/how-do-i-stay-motivated-while-planning-a-series-of-novels), but I thought I would just ask it again anyways.)

Comment: "I thought I would just ask it again anyways" isn't really an excuse for asking a duplicate. Fortunately for you, I don't think this *is* a duplicate - this is specifically about planning a timeline, whereas the linked question is much more general.

Comment: Even if it was a duplicate, I wanted to ask because that previous post *was* written five years ago. What if someone new, someone who didn't comment on the previous post, had something to add? For example, what would you say about this point?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with posting answers to old questions here on Stack Exchange. If someone has something new to contribute to an old question, there's nothing stopping them from posting an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Preliminary Remarks**

There are two ways to write (and any mix between them): "pantsing" or "discovery writing" and "planning" or "outlining".

Pantsers, as the word implies, disover the story as they write it, navigating its development by feel, writing "by the seat of their pants". The problem with this approach is that the writer might later disover turns that make is necessary to adapt the earlier parts. Also, driven as these kind of writers are by following their ideas, their plots may not always have good tension or even contain plot holes. All this usually necessitates heavy  or complete rewriting. One novelist (whose name I forget) said he just rewrote his whole novels several times until the result was satisfactory.

Outliners plan the story in as much detail as necessary to structure their story well and avoid any problems with consistency and plot progress. The problem with this approach is that writing often doesn't feel as exciting. But it usually doesn't require as much rewriting as pantsing does.

Some writers employ a mix of both techniques, planning out the rough movements of the story but leaving enough to discover.

Certain genres are so complex that they cannot be discovery-written. For example, a who-dunnit detective novel requires careful planning of what clues are revealed when, and an epic fantasy about court intrigue require careful planning of how the factions are related, when they work togther, when agains each other, what the effects are etc. If the structure of your story is very complex and multidimensional, planning is usually necessary. The more linear your story is and the more it follows the internal viewpoint of only one character, the more it lends itself to discovery writing.

**How to Find Your Personal Way to Map Out a Timeline**

If you want to plan your narrative, employ all the necessary tools. Use tables (for example in a spreadsheet) to list your characters and their traits. Draw a diagram to visualize the development of a character's emotions or a network map for the relationships between many players.

For a timeline, certain representations have been established, and there is software to help you with creating it. I recommend that you do a Google image search for "timeline", "timelines", "timeline software", "timeline graph", "timeline diagram" and similar search terms to see what comes up. Do not forget to search for "timeline writing" or "timeline author" and such. You will find graphs of timelines that some well-known authors have used for their work. I remember seeing one by J. K. Rowling for *Harry Potter*. This might inspire you. Scroll through the images and see what appeals to you and what fits your current idea of the timeline structure of your narrative.

Then sit down and try to draw the rough timelines of your tale on paper. Label (only) the important points. Play around with different kinds of representation to find the one that seems to fit your story best.

Then draw it out with all the necessary detail either on a large enough sheet of paper or buy the app that does that kind of graph. I prefer paper. To my way of drawing diagrams it is more flexible (most software cannot draw everything but is limited by its functionality while on paper I can have gaps and diverging or crossing lines or whatever I want). Also, I find drawing by hand on paper more satsifying, and I can think better on paper than in a software. But people are different, so maybe try out a software that appeals to you. Many offer a free trial period.

---

**Note**

Some things you say remind me of ADHD. If that is what you suffer from, you may want to learn about how to treat and live with ADHD as an adult. Structuring yourself is usually an important part of it, as well as observing and understanding your attention span and how to deal with distractions.

Comment: [Origin of the phrase "flying by the seat of your pants."](https://postalmuseum.si.edu/exhibition/fad-to-fundamental-airmail-in-america-airmail-flight-school-by-the-seat-of-your-pants-7)  That's what "pantser" refers to.

Comment: @JRE Indeed: "**the seat of one's pants**: a person's (originally a pilot's) sensitivity to the movement or vibration of an aeroplane, motor vehicle, etc., used as a guide in controlling it. Hence, more generally, in **by the seat of one's pants**: by instinct and experience rather than logic, expert knowledge, or technical aid. Also in extended uses." (https://www.oed.com/dictionary/pants_n?tab=meaning_and_use#32212172)

Comment: @Ben Thank you so much for your feedback and for sharing what you do; I will definitely use some of this. (And yes, I do have ADHD .)